# How to calculate the minimum depth of binary tree

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

Here is the question from the leetcode:
Given a binary tree, find its minimum depth.
The minimum depth is the number of nodes along the shortest path from the root node down to the nearest leaf node.
If i understand correctly,it means if i have a tree

```
                                                8
                                               / \
                                              3   10
                                             /
                                            1
```

the min depth is supposed to be 2 (from node 8 to 10).
However, from the these two links with python code:
http://codesays.com/2014/solution-to-minimum-depth-of-binary-tree-by-leetcode/
https://gist.github.com/Ray1988/9374678
Result i compiled is 3!!! which makes me so much confused.....

Comment: well..i dont know why the figure does not show..Here is what i meant: root is 8,its left child is 3 and right child is 10.And 3 has its left child 1....Thanks

Comment: Could the code perhaps have interpreted a tree with only a root to have a depth of 1? Are all paths returned 1 more than what you expect?

Comment: I looked at both chunks of code and they seem to return 2 (as would be expected). Granted, I am not a Python interpreter and I'm too lazy to go run the code so I can't say for sure but...it just seems like you are wrong about what those solutions return. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either a depth-first, or a depth-first search can find the nearest leaf to the root. BFS can be arbitrarily faster than searching over the whole tree (as is necessary for DFS), although it will in general use more memory.

Here's a full example for both implementations, both of which return the minimum depth of the tree, and a leaf node that's at that minimum depth. Depth-first is easier to implement than breadth-first because it's easy to represent a depth-first algorithm using recursion.

```
import collections
import heapq

Node = collections.namedtuple('Node', ['v', 'children'])

def min_depth_bfs(root):
    todo = [(1, root)]
    while todo:
        depth, node = heapq.heappop(todo)
        if not node.children: return depth, node
        for c in node.children:
            heapq.heappush(todo, (depth + 1, c))

def min_depth_dfs(node):
    if not node.children: return 1, node
    d, n = min(min_depth_dfs(c) for c in node.children)
    return 1 + d, n

example = Node(8, [Node(3, [Node(1, [])]), Node(10, [])])

print min_depth_dfs(example)
print min_depth_bfs(example)
```